# Iostream is a class

Tags: c++, class, header-files

i read in Turbo c++ in help tab that iostream is a class but till I knw my lecturer taught us that it is an header file so which one is true iostream is an header file or a class??

Comment: I suggest you [pick up a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2):

... Or both. You can include the header `<iostream>` and there is a type `std::iostream`

Comment: so...iostream is basically...a header...not a class??

Comment: @keerthi, You probably wouldn't ever use the class directly, but it's there inside the header.

Comment: @keerthi: There is a header file `<iostream>` and there is a class template `std::iostream`

Comment: @keerthi: [This reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) shows how the stream-based I/O library is organized.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, I was 2 seconds too late on that :p

Comment: @Blastfurnace: so finally what do u call iostream??...class/header??

Comment: @keerthi: Both. There is a header file called `<iostream>` and there is also `std::iostream` which is a class template typedef.

Answer (score 1):

iostream is indeed a class in C++. You obtain access to this class by including the file named iostream in your code:

```
// SomeFile.cpp
#include <iostream>

// Some code that makes use of the class iostream...
```

This also holds for other stream classes within C++ such as istream, ostream, fstream, and so forth. Dig around in the include directory of your C++ installation to get a look at these classes if you wish.

This is of course a very common situation in C++ since one often encounters classes whose actual definitions are stored in files with the same name as the class but with .hpp or .cpp extensions.

Comment: so...iostream is a file/header file...in which iostream class exists and which we use in our programs??right??